# Rescaling multivariable normal pdf and normalizing constant

Tags: probability-distributions, jacobian, change-of-variable

I am trying to understand change of variables for a random variable and how it changes the pdf and the normalizing constant.

Let $\mathbf{w}$ be $N$-dimensional normal variable and let $\mathbf{S}$ be covariance matrix. I can diagonalize that matrix: $\mathbf{S} =\mathbf{O \Sigma O^T} $ and change original variable: $\mathbf{ x = O^T w} $. Now I have diagonal covariance matrix that I call $\mathbf{\Sigma_x}$, and probability density function for $x$ is

$$
P_x(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x} \mathbf{x}\}}{\int d\mathbf{x} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x} \mathbf{x}\}} = (2\pi)^{-N/2} (\det \mathbf{\Sigma_x})^{-\frac12} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x} \mathbf{x}\}
$$

Now I make the change of variable to $\mathbf{y} = a \mathbf{x}$ and calculate Jacobian. Function for change of variable is $g(x) = a x$ and $g^{-1}(y) = a^{-1} y$ so according to the changing variable method new pdf must be

$$
P_y(\mathbf{y}) = P_x(g^{-1}(y)) \begin{vmatrix} \frac{d g^{-1}(y)}{dy}\end{vmatrix}
$$

where $\begin{vmatrix} \frac{d g^{-1}(y)}{dy}\end{vmatrix}$ is Jacobian. For case of rescaling of the variable this is just $\begin{vmatrix} a^{-1}\end{vmatrix}$. So pdf for $y$ is

$$
P_y(\mathbf{y}) = (2\pi)^{-N/2} [\det (a\ \mathbf{\Sigma_x} \ a)]^{-\frac12} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\} \\= a^{-N} (2\pi)^{-N/2} [\det (\mathbf{\Sigma_x})]^{-\frac12} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}
$$

Now I try to calculate this result by making substitution $\mathbf{x}=a^{-1}\mathbf{y}$ in $P_x(\mathbf{x})$, but I get different answer for the integral in normalizing constant.
$$
P_y(\mathbf{y}) = \frac{\exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}}{\int d\mathbf{y} a^{-N} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}}
$$

The denominator above is normalizing constant and is a gauss integral
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{N}&=a^{-N} \int d\mathbf{y}\exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\} = a^{-N} (2\pi)^{N/2} [\det a^2 \mathbf{\Sigma_x}]^{1/2} \\&= a^{-N}a^{N} (2\pi)^{N/2} [\det \mathbf{\Sigma_x}]^{1/2} = (2\pi)^{N/2} [\det \mathbf{\Sigma_x}]^{1/2}
\end{align}
$$
So the $a$ is cancelling out here and new pdf is
$$
P_y(\mathbf{y}) = (2\pi)^{-N/2} [\det (\mathbf{\Sigma_x})]^{-\frac12} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}
$$

I don't understand why this is different from answer I got when using Jacobian formula? I must have made mistakes in the integral. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for $P_y(\mathbf y)$ should be
$$
P_y(\mathbf{y}) = \frac{a^{-N} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}}{\int d\mathbf{y} \ a^{-N} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}}.
$$
i.e. the factor of $a^{-N}$ should appear in the numerator too.

Remember, the whole point of the normalization factor $\int d\mathbf{y} \ a^{-N} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}$ in the denominator is to ensure that $\int d\mathbf y P_y(\mathbf y) = 1$.

Staring at my expression, it's clear that $\int d\mathbf y P_y(\mathbf y) = 1$.

But with your expression in your question, it's clear that you'd get $\int d\mathbf y P_y(\mathbf y) = a^N$, which isn't right.

---

**To address point raised in comments...**

It's legitimate to substitute variables inside the integral. There, we're substituting one dummy variable for another dummy variable, which is fine. For example, it's legitimate to write
$$
P_x(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x} \mathbf{x}\}}{\int d\mathbf{x'} \ \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{x'}^T \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x} \mathbf{x'}\}} = \frac{\exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x} \mathbf{x}\}}{\int d\mathbf{u} \ a^{-N} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{u}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{u}\}}.
$$
where we've performed a variable substitution $\mathbf {x'} = a^{-1} \mathbf u$ inside the integral.

But to derive $P_y(\mathbf {y})$ from $P_x(\mathbf {x})$, you **must** use the Jacobian. That is the **only** legitimate way to get the expression for $P_y(\mathbf {y})$.
$$ P_y(\mathbf y) = P_x(\mathbf x) \left| \frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial \mathbf y}\right| = a^{-N} P_x(\mathbf x) = \frac{a^{-N}\exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x} \mathbf{x}\}}{\int d\mathbf{u} \ a^{-N} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{u}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{u}\}}$$

---

**NB** The correct way to change variables for the pdf is to use the Jacobian formula,
$$ P_y(\mathbf y) = P_x(\mathbf x) \left| \frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial \mathbf y}\right| = a^{-N} P_x(\mathbf x)  .$$

It is **incorrect** to say that
$$ P_y(\mathbf y) = P_x(\mathbf x)  $$

Why is this?

Consider a infinitesimal volume element $\delta \mathbf x$ in $\mathbf x$-space, which maps to an infinitesimal volume element $\delta \mathbf y$ in $\mathbf y$-space. What is the probability that the sample lies in this infinitesimal volume element?

We can calculate this probability in two ways - using the $\mathbf x$-space representation or using the $\mathbf y$-space representation. The two answers must be equal. In other words,

$$ P_x(\mathbf x) \delta \mathbf x = P_y(\mathbf y) \delta \mathbf y.$$

But the volumes of the volume elements are different! They are related by
$$ \delta \mathbf x = \left| \frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial \mathbf y}\right| \times \delta \mathbf y.$$

Hence it follows that
$$ P_x(\mathbf x) \left| \frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial \mathbf y}\right| = P_y(\mathbf y).$$

Comment: I believe that integral of first expression for $P_y(\mathbf{y}=(2\pi)^{-N/2} [\det (a\ \mathbf{\Sigma_x} \ a)]^{-\frac12} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\})$ equals to 1:
$$
(2\pi)^{-N/2} [\det (a\ \mathbf{\Sigma_x} \ a)]^{-\frac12} \int \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\} = (2\pi)^{-N/2} [\det (a\ \mathbf{\Sigma_x} \ a)]^{-\frac12} (2\pi)^{N/2} [\det (a\ \mathbf{\Sigma_x} \ a)]^{\frac12}.
$$
Is this not correct?

Comment: I was talking about the expression $P_y(\mathbf{y}) = \frac{ \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}}{\int d\mathbf{y} \ a^{-N} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}}$. Clearly this doesn't integrate to $1$. It integrates to $a^N$.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am asking how come substitution of variables gives this wrong answer. I thought that it should be equivalent to using Jacobian.

Comment: @sk1995 See my edit. Does that help?

Comment: @ Kenny Wong. Yes it helps. Thanks! So my question is then just for normalizing constant. How it changes when variable is rescaled? 
$$
\int d\mathbf{u} a^{-N} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{u^T} a^{-2} \mathbf{\Sigma_x}^{-1} \mathbf{u}\} =a^{-N} a^{N} (2\pi)^{N/2} [\det \mathbf{\Sigma_x}]^{1/2}=(2\pi)^{N/2} [\det \mathbf{\Sigma_x}]^{1/2}
$$
so normalizing constant does not change?

Comment: @sk1995 Correct. $\int d\mathbf{x'} \ \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{x'}^T \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x} \mathbf{x'}\}$ and $\int d\mathbf{u} \ a^{-N} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{u}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{u}\}$ are both equal to $(2\pi)^{N/2} [\det \mathbf \Sigma_x ]^{1/2}$.

Comment: Can you explain idea for why substitution of the variable is not right way to change variables of pdf? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @sk1995 See the new edit. Does this help?

Comment: yes I think I understand. I will read more about it.